# how can i use facebook analytics push notification in react native?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, facebook-analytics

i want to use facebook analytics push campaigns in my app.
i have successed integrated the ios part, but android part was failed

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/push-campaigns/android?locale=en_US

i used [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) and could receive the notification from GCM in my app.

so anyone can help to set up push campaigns for Android in React native ?

thank you !